# Is there a (standard) font with a literal end-of-line character in it?

Tags: symbols, line-breaking

For ... complicated ... reasons (which I'll explain in a moment), I want to be able to put a literal end-of-line character in my document.  Simply putting `^^J` results in an Ω.  Looking at the font tables in *TeX by Topic*, that seems quite reasonable as the slot occupied by character 10 - corresponding to the inputted eol - is, indeed, Ω.  Looking further at the font tables, I can't see an eol symbol in the standard TeX fonts (why would it be there?).  So I went searching in other fonts and of course they have the symbol, but I can't figure how to get it in to the document.  So:

How do I get a literal end-of-line character in to a document?

(*The rest isn't necessary to understand the question, just the background*)

My reason for wanting this is strange, but hopefully comprehensible.  I'm coercing TeX into being a *pre-processor*.  A step in this is to use `pdftotext` to convert the output from TeX into an ordinary text file (suitable for feeding back into another system).  Now for my desired next step, line endings seem to be significant.  So I want to control where they end up.  However, unless I have a sheet of (virtual) paper 20m wide, I also need to let TeX break lines where it will (since either TeX or PDF or `pdftotext` truncate long lines).  I thought that I could get around this by using the fact that there are different systems for line-breaks on different computers, and `pdftotext` is nice enough to work with all of them.  So I can tell `pdftotext` to *convert* the linebreaks in the PDF to, say, character 13 whilst putting character 10 where I actually want them.  But that strategy hinges on being able to put some sort of actual eol character in the output, which I don't seem to be able to do.

Comment: What output format are you targeting? I'm asking because one of my long term ideas is to program a DocbookXML class which outputs the XML code (but also allows normal LaTeX compilation) :-)

Comment: @Martin: I want plain-old ASCII text.  This is only a step in a chain.  What I want is to be able to distinguish linebreaks put in by TeX's linebreaking mechanism from linebreaks that I've declared should be there.  A bit like "hard" linebreaks and "soft" linebreaks in Emacs.

Comment: You could select a very large textwidth so that TeX never breaks lines by itself. (Edit: Just read Ulrike's answer which says the same :-) )

Comment: I have seen fonts that include an EOL character (generally, three tiny letters in a diagonal descending from the top left), but can't actually name any of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are confusing the coding of end-of-lines in a textfile with the coding of end-of-lines in a format like pdf which is orientated toward a page description. E.g. if I insert `Hello\\World` in a tex document the resulting pdf then contains this:

`/F16 9.9626 Tf 133.768 707.125 Td [(Hello)]TJ 0 -11.955 Td [(W)80(orld)]TJ`

Beside this: I doubt that you actually need a 20m sheet (assuming that your paragraphs have a normal length). When I want to copy text from pdf's and want to avoid trouble with linebreak I'm using 1m and in general that's quite enough.

Comment: I think you're probably right: it's highly likely that I'm confused!  Experimenting with my current document leads to a 2m page width, so with TeX's maximum of just under 6m then I'm probably safe with that method.  Thanks.